# center tikz figure in beamer generated by quarto

Tags: beamer, quarto, tikz

I have a quarto document that I'm compiling as a beamer that contains a tikz picture.

````
---
format: 
  beamer:
    keep-tex: true
    theme: Antibes
---

## my picture

```{tikz}
#| echo: false

\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

for some reason, I can't get the figure to be vertically align on the beamer slide. I tried the `fig-align` attribute in the document properties and well as the `\centering` statement in the tikz chunk, but nothing seems to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, adding the `fig.align` attribute to the tikz chunk had the desired effect.

````
```{tikz}
#| echo: false
#| fig.align: center

\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the tikzpicture in a `center` environment:

```
---
format: 
  beamer:
    keep-tex: true
    theme: Antibes
---

## my picture

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

text
```

[image]